# Add last two value of an array for every time array is method invoked in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I would like to write a program where whenever a method is called the last two digits in the array are added.

So for example, if the method/array is

```
def add
 array = [1,2,3,4]
end
```

And if I call `array`,it should return me `7 (4 + 3)`. If I call `array` again, it should return `9 (7+2)`. Since `4` and `3` are now replaced with `7`.

The way I thought of doing but have been unsuccesful is

```
def add
        num = 0
        @sum = [1,2,3]
        @sum.map{|w| sum += w}.last
      end

def result 
 return add
end
```

And this how I invoke it

```
class = Test.new
class.add
class.result # Should return 7
class.add
class.result #should return 9
```

Comment: `array`? isn't it `add`?

Comment: sorry i just fixed it.

Comment: "if invoke it again it should return 6" - why? I don't see that.

Comment: I have commented it but, if class.add and class.result is executed again it should return 6. Since it needs to take the last 2 digits remaining in the array in consideration.

Comment: @PrakamyaSharma You initialize the array on each call to `add` how do you expect the result to change?

Comment: Right. I can also have a different method just to return array. In add I can write/update the existing array. But not sure how.

Comment: Hello @IvayloStrandjev , I have updated the question again. please take a look.thanks :)

Comment: Instead of doing 1+2 = 3, 3+3 = 6. Its 3+2 = 5, 5 + 1. Reversing the adding method..Hope that makes sense :P

Comment: @PrakamyaSharma I am sorry this question is still not at all clear to me. I can show you how to write a method that takes a string as argument and replaces its last two elements with their sum as this seems to be part of the question but the remaining part I simply do not understand

Comment: give me some time. I will rephrase. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prakmya, someone downvoted you because your question is difficult to understand. Firstly, why are you bothering with `class Tests` and `attr_accessor :map`? I wonder where did you cargo-cult that :-) One possible way of doing what you (perhaps) want would be:

```
def join_last_2 array
  return if array.empty?
  last = array.pop
  if array.empty? then
    array << last
  else
    array[-1] = array[-1] + last
  end
end

a = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
join_last_2( a )
#=> 9
a
#=> [1, 2, 3, 9]
join_last_2( a )
#=> 12
a
#=> [1, 2, 12]
# etc.
```

Comment: Yes, I rephrased it. I was pasting snippets from my code. I should have posted the entire code. sorry. I understand now why it is difficult. And thanks so much @BorisStitnicky . It exactly does what want )